# Count when a user order a product

Tags: php, laravel

I want make count when a user login and make order about some product
This is my table

- User :
  Id(1 to many->order), name, email, address, phone
- order :
  Id, id_user, id_product, date, price, total_order, total_price

I have written

```
$count = order::where('id_user','Auth->user()')->count();
```

Code above does not work, if I write like this

```
$count = order::all()->count();
```

It work but count all the data even i login with different user

Comment: Change `'Auth->user()'` to `auth()->user()->id` or `auth()->id()` notice the *single quotes*

Comment: there is mistake of you. Should be `$count = order::where('id_user', auth()->id())->count();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try this its working properly

```
$count = order::where('id_user',auth()->user()->id)->count();
```

OR

```
$count = order::where('id_user',auth()->id())->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

`'Auth->user()'` firstly you tried a string not the id of logged user, you have to remove the quotation marks and add the `use Auth;` to import this class and then use it.

```php
use Auth;

$count = order::where('id_user', Auth::user()->id)->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a relation from the user model

```php
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Then you can call wherever you want like this

```php
auth()->user()->orders->count()
```